# High logical reads for a simple query

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

I have a very simple query  like

```
select col1,col2 from table A where pk_col =1
```

where pk_col is a primary key.

When I run this query with statistics IO and time ON,I get below

```
(1 row affected)
Table 'A'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2948, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

SQL Server Execution Times:
 `CPU time = 46 ms,  elapsed time = 105 ms.`

1)Why are logical reads so high even though only record is being retrieved ?

Comment: is pk_col of type string? Please, show the DDL to create table and table indexes.

Comment: @JesúsLópez  hmmm .yes.pk_col is a varchar.When  I put single quote around it .it ran real fast.

Comment: looks like, your problem is the mingling of types, the index is not being used because the thing you searched on doesn't have the type of the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `pk_col` is `varchar` SQL Server needs to convert `pk_col` to `int` because `int` has higher precedence:

[Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

So the query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM table A 
where CONVERT(int, pk_col) =1
```

And enclosing columns into functions or expressions prevents SQL Server from using indexes. Therefore SQL Server has to scan the entire table. Hence the high number of logical reads